Observer Pattern Question - function not working
coding in unity/C#
Ok so I am currently trying to improve my coding skills so I have been looking into the Observer Pattern, I have run into one issue currently. My upgrade button script has the event OnClick() that invokes the Action OnUpgrade and passes itself(the script) as a parameter to the listener within UpgradeManager (UpgradeClick(UpgradeButton button)), and it works up until it tells the upgrade button to make itself invisible upgradebutton.TurnOff(). Is there a way for my manager to tell the button to turn itself off or should I not use the observer pattern for this.
the way I had it before was the button would call the UpgradeClick function within the manager, but as I scale up and add a lot more buttons even with prefabs I would need to fix each one
UpgradeButton.cs   
public static event Action<UpgradeButton> OnUpgrade;
public void OnClick()
{
    OnUpgrade?.Invoke(this);
}

UpgradeManager.cs
UpgradeButton.OnUpgrade += UpgradeClick;
public void UpgradeClick(UpgradeButton upgradeButton)
{
    if(scoreManager.GetScore()>= upgradeButton.GetCost())
    {
        scoreManager.DecScore(upgradeButton.GetCost());
        clickMultiplier += upgradeButton.GetUpgrade();
        upgradeButton.TurnOff();
    }
}


Could UpgradeClick check whether the button is turned off, and branch accordingly?

I think the issue here is a not clear enough separation into MVC/MVP .. meaning your button is currently both, a view (UI) as well as a model (cost and upgrade level) .. if you would clearer separate the view from the model you would rather have a UI button that would listen to changes in the model so it would already know whether it should be visible according to the model

Besides that though .. why does it not work the way you have it? What is the issue with your manager telling the button to TurnOff ?
